# Azure Webapp: Unable to install docker buildx in SSH

Tags: linux, azure, docker, ssh, azure-web-app-service

I'm running an App Service on Azure. I can SSH into the Linux terminal.

Linux version: Debian 9.13 (Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch))

When running:

`apt-get install docker-buildx-plugin`

I get:

`E: Unable to locate package docker-buildx-plugin`

I tried

`RUN apt-get update`

And all steps mentioned in this Install [Docker Engine guide](https://docs.docker.com/engine/install/ubuntu/#install-docker-engine)

Comment: What is the framework and version of your WebApp?

Comment: Where do I find the framework and version? @Harshitha

Comment: First run this command `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh  
and then run `sh get-docker.sh` .

Comment: Again run `docker buildx version` to check the installed version of docker .[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Ihl6.png)

Comment: Will post the answer in detail.

Comment: `What is the framework and version of your WebApp?` Ignore this comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Even I got the same error as you have shown when I run the command `apt-get install docker-buildx-plugin`.

[image]

Thanks @[tiborvass](https://github.com/krallin/docker/blob/master/hack/install.sh) for the commands.

I have taken reference from the above document.

Run the below command.

```cs
curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh
```

This command will run the `docker-buildx-plugin`.

[image]

- Now run `docker buildx version` to check the installed version.

[image]

- Now try to run the command which you have tried initially.

```cs
apt-get install docker-buildx-plugin
```

Iam not getting the error now.

[image]

Comment: Running the command `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh` 
leads it to say: 

`E: Unable to locate package docker-compose-plugin
E: Unable to locate package docker-ce-rootless-extras
E: Unable to locate package docker-buildx-plugin`

Comment: I have tried in multiple apps with the success result.

Comment: Framework is available in `Configuration` => `General Settings`.

Comment: There is no Framework under Configuration => General Settings, in my interface. Maybe because I am using the cheapest option?

Comment: Thank you, it worked when I made a fresh new Web App, using Node 18. Some of the internal settings may have been changed too much while trying to make the previous WebApp work. 

On a fresh build this was enough: `curl -sSL https://get.docker.com/ | sh`

Comment: This answer works fine for WSL2 as well, you just need to restart the docker service to avoid Error 111: `sudo service docker.service restart`.